# Plot dictionary produced by Python program using Scilab

Tags: python, plot, scilab

I know that I can plot my python-generated data by `matplotlib`. The reason why I want to plot my data using Scilab is keeping plotted figure the same style. Because I already have plotted many figures using Scilab.

Should I use `subprocess.Popen` to run a scilab script? Is there a better way than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sciscipy`](http://www.scilab.org/scilab/interoperability/calculation_engine/python) python package seems to provide interface to Scilab features inside Python.

An example for you to assess if this is what you want:

```
from scilab import Scilab
sci = Scilab()
x = sci.rand(20, 20)
y = x*x.transpose()
y_inv = sci.inv(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your python script interact with your scilab plotting script through sockets. Here's how you send data from python:

```
import socket                                              
import sys                                                 

host = socket.gethostname()                                
port = 59981                                               
try:                                                       
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.bind((host, port))                                 
except socket.error:                                       
    print "Unable to setup"                                

soc.listen(5)                                              
while True:                                                
    conn, addr = soc.accept()                              
    conn.send("data")                                      
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. :-) Interesting. I will try when I have time. deadline approaching, not enough time to try socket....